# ag-grid, cant name colId with 'name'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid

I want to have column with colId= 'name', and also to use the CellRenderer to make the option to double click on the name(like link)

The problem is when i give colId='name', cellRenderer doesn't get the object correctly..., how I solved this is that I renamed the colId='Name'

If I delete the CellRenderer and keep the colId='name' it works, but I need CellRenderer
But I don't want to rename colId with 'Name'

name col:

```
            colId: 'name', headerName: this.$translate.instant('Name'),
            field: 'name', value: 'name',
            comparator: AgGridUtils.stringComparator,
            cellRenderer: this.nameCellRenderer,
            minWidth: 170
```

Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us with some code? such as the `cellRenderer` function as well as the colDef for that column? or create a jsfiddle from [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/jrmoser/vrw6hufc/) that recreates your problem?

Comment: @JarodMoser I cant share my code, but I edited the thread and added the options of name